# base type equality check fails

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, types

Just stumbled across this. Here's my scenario:

```
|--> BaseTypeLibrary  (contains ViewModelBase)
|--> ModelLibrary     (contains Model)
|--> Business Library (contains equality check)

 public class Model : ViewModelBase{ }

 // returns false
 bool isViewModel = (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ViewModelBase)));
```

First I've made sure that the UI Library's and ModelLibrary's references point to the same BaseTypeLibrary. Here's a few checks that I perform.

```
 // false
 Console.WriteLine(type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ViewModelBase)));

 // true
 Console.WriteLine((type.BaseType == typeof(ViewModelBase)));

 // true
 Console.WriteLine((typeof(ViewModelBase).Module.FullyQualifiedName) == (type.BaseType.Module.FullyQualifiedName));

 //true
 Console.WriteLine(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ViewModelBase)));
```

Can anyone explain why IsAssignableFrom fails?

Comment: how to you get `type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a common issue that trips people up when they first use `IsAssignableFrom`.

In your example, you'll need to reverse the instance and the argument when you perform the check:

```
bool isViewModel = typeof(ViewModelBase).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

> public virtual bool IsAssignableFrom( Type c )
>
> Return Value Type: System.Boolean
>
> true if c and the current Type represent the same type,
> **or if the current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of c, or if the
> current Type is an interface that c implements**, or if c is a generic
> type parameter and the current Type represents one of the constraints
> of c. false if none of these conditions are true, or if c is null.

So you'll need to call the method *on* the candidate base/interface-type and use the candidate concrete/sub-type as the method *argument*.

I would agree that the way the method is named is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Although it's pretty obvious...a `Model` is a `ViewModelBase`, but not the other way round...